# PHP Submit Form Problems

Tags: php, html

I've looked around for fixes but none seem to be working.
I have a barcode scanner which inputs the barcode and clicks enter on the textbox, I then want the form to echo the result of the PHP function however it doesn't want to.

HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form actiom="" method="Get">
            <input type="text" placeholder="scan barcode" name="barcoded" onkeydown="getproduct()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$matchedproducts = [
    '534513'     => "iSmoka Eleaf iKiss Mini",
    '798154'     => "iSmoka Eleaf iStick 20W",
    '223701'     => "iSmoka Eleaf iStick 50W",
    '811693'     => "iSmoka Eleaf i118",
    '796026'     => "E-Liquid"
];
$barcode = $_GET['barcodeid'];
$productfound = FALSE;
    function getproduct() {
    foreach ($matchedproducts as $id => $product) {
        if ($barcode == array_search($barcode, $matchedproducts[$id])) {
            $productfound = TRUE;
            echo $matchedproducts[$product];

        } else {
            $productfound = FALSE;
            echo "No product";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I have all the code in the same file.

Comment: php is server side. Javascript is on the client side. You can't call getproduct() that way. You need to submit the form before your php can do anything with the data

Comment: It appears that you are calling getproduct() (a PHP function) from the wrong place. I assume you want to retrieve data from the server on the onkeyup event. You should make yourself familiar with AJAX.

Comment: why aren't you looking up the product with a database call?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that in your form you have different name then in your php code.
In your php you searching for value of `$_GET[barcodeid]`:

```
$barcode = $_GET['barcodeid'];
```

And in your html you have `name=barcode`

```
<input type="text" placeholder="scan barcode" name="barcoded" onkeydown="getproduct()">
```

Also missing to check if $_GET['barcodeid'] is set.

Also in your input field you are calling JS function `getproduct()` and not a php function

Comment: This is correct but it will not help until the form is submitted!

Comment: true but he doesn't have also submit button, so basically lots of stuff missing from this code

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you're using PHP for this? 
You could just have a javascript function that does what you need to do. It would also mean you don't need to have a server.

If you need to use PHP because you also want to do other things which can't easily be done in javascript or would give the game away to people looking at the source, you should just make use of the general "post" functionality.

If you go down the 2nd route, you can then check for $_POST["barcoded"] in your PHP and echo whatever you want.

Visit http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp for some help.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side script, while JavaScript is client-side. When you use `onkeydown="getproduct()"`, the page thinks you're calling the JavaScript function `getproduct()`. Instead, if you want to call a php function, submit the form to a `.php` page, and have the function there.

```
<form action="function.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" placeholder="scan barcode" name="barcoded" onkeydown="getproduct()">
    </form>
```

function.php:

```
<?php
$matchedproducts = [
    '534513'     => "iSmoka Eleaf iKiss Mini",
    '798154'     => "iSmoka Eleaf iStick 20W",
    '223701'     => "iSmoka Eleaf iStick 50W",
    '811693'     => "iSmoka Eleaf i118",
    '796026'     => "E-Liquid"
];

// Changed to barcoded, instead of barcodeid
$barcode = $_GET['barcoded'];
$productfound = FALSE;
    foreach ($matchedproducts as $id => $product) {
        if ($barcode == array_search($barcode, $matchedproducts[$id])) {
            $productfound = TRUE;
            echo $matchedproducts[$product];

        } else {
            $productfound = FALSE;
            echo "No product";
        }
    }
?>
```